# Is there a way to install ubuntu to Windows ME without a USB drive or burning a disk?

Tags: system-installation

I have Windows ME on a PC that I want to install Ubuntu to but i don't have a CD burner and at present don't have access to a USB drive.

If i had to i could get a USB drive but i was hoping to avoid that.

I did a search on google and the most relevant information i could find was at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromWindows

However when i try to do "The Netboot Approach" in step 2 it tells me to "Download linux and initrd.gz from http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/gutsy/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/ubuntu-installer/i386/ " but when i click the link to do this i get a "the requested URL was not found" message.

Could someone please tell me where i can find linux and initrd.gz or tell me another way that i can go about installing Ubuntu without a CD or USB drive?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: @mikewhatever suggesting that someone use an EOL release isn't a constructive use of comments...

Comment: @TheLordofTime Why not? Given the fact, the OP uses WindowsME, I rather doubt, anything currently supported would pose as a viable alternative. Last, but not least, I've not suggested the use of Gutsy; just corrected an outdated link from the howto.

Comment: @mikewhatever if you have a link to the linux and initrd.gz files that it says i need i should be able to geton with doing the installation.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work. But try this. Take the drive from the ME box and move it to another pc that has a cd drive and do a regular Ubuntu install from cd. Then move the drive back to the ME box.